# Detecting Last View UIViewController

Tags: uiviewcontroller, ios7, nsuserdefaults

I am trying to program a page so that when I click the 'Return' button I got the the last visited UIViewController.

Last Page Code:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:NSStringFromClass([self class]) forKey:@"currentViewController"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Return Button Code:

```
    - (IBAction)Return:(id)sender {
        NSString *savedClassName = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"currentViewController"];
UIViewController *screen = (UIViewController *)NSClassFromString(savedClassName);
screen.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
[self presentModalViewController:screen animated:YES];
            }
```

The problem is it keeps returning the error:

```
+[SAVEDVIEWNAME setModalTransitionStyle:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x59b98
2013-12-14 12:47:27.462 Friends+[16358:a0b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[Calander setModalTransitionStyle:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x59b98'
```

I understand what it's trying to say, but it's not making sense as that is perfectly acceptable in this instance!!!

Any help appreciated, thnx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to instantiate an objcet from the class, like so:

```
NSString *savedClassName = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"currentViewController"];
Class cls = NSClassFromString(savedClassName);
UIViewController *screen = (UIViewController *)[cls new];
screen.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
[self presentViewController:screen animated:YES completion:nil]; //You should use this instead of presentModalViewController:animated: !
```

Comment: When I press it, it fades to black. I'm using a storyboard btw.

Comment: @SebOH In that case, you shouldn't save the class of the view controller, but have a storyboard ID and save that. Then use `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:` to create your view.